# Managing channels using a HTTP request context

Tags: http, go, concurrency, channel

I have a basic HTTP server that accepts a request and returns data from a data store.

Each HTTP request does the following things:

1. Create a context with timeout
2. Create a read request (custom type)
3. Push read request onto channel
4. Wait for response and serve data

Here's the basic pseudo code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type dataRequest struct {
    data chan string
    ctx  context.Context
}

func handler(reqStream chan dataRequest) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(r.Context(), 5*time.Second)
        defer cancel()

        req := dataRequest{
            data: make(chan string),
            ctx:  ctx,
        }

        select {
        case reqStream <- req:
            // request pushed to que
        case <-ctx.Done():
            // don't push onto reqStream if ctx done
        }

        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            // don't try and serve content if ctx done
        case data := <-req.data:
            // return data to client
        }

    }
}

func main() {
    dataReqs := make(chan dataRequest)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case req := <-dataReqs:
                select {
                case <-req.ctx.Done():
                    // don't push onto data channel if ctx done
                case req.data <- "some data":
                    // get data from store
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler(dataReqs))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

My question is, because the context could finish at any time due to the deadline being exceeded or the client cancelling the request, is my current approach correct for handling this in multiple places or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that it'll work. 
few comments -

1. you can `return` in the first case of `<- ctx.Done()`
2. you're already waiting for `req.ctx.Done()` in the data store handler so you can completely remove the first `select {}` statement and just publish to the data requests channel. not sure about performance hits for the rare cases when the context is done so early before the request is even published...